# GlassFish stops giving response

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have GlassFish-4 running a Store Administration System. I had a design problem and i moved to a new project in NetBeans.
 My installation of GlassFish works for 1 or 2 requests and then it stops giving response. Chrome says No Response Data. When i try to locate the resource through 8181 it still works and the admin port is also working fine.
The server log has no Exceptions or anything. When i checked the memory usage the java process holds about 380MB that is not much more than when i loaded the glassfish it self. 
I have hiberante running and a custom json parser, hence there is not much of a memory problem.

I am a student and i am new to this, so thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question

The problems seems to be cache! I didn't find any way to clear the cache effectively but i moved my application to a new glass fish install and it worked like a charm.